# Enabling MvcBuildViews for MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: model-view-controller, mvcsitemapprovider, .net-4.6

I am working on a MVC 5 project using MvcBuildViews and MvcSiteMapProvider. We are trying to enable MvcBuildViews by editing the project file with:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

and

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

After doing this, we try to build the site. The compiler returns these errors in the SiteMapProvider templates:

> - The name 'model' does not exist in the current context c:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXXXX\packages\MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.4.6.1\content\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\SiteMapHelperModel.cshtml
> - 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXXXX\packages\MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.4.6.1\content\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\SiteMapNodeModelList.cshtml

What do I need to do in order to get the MvcBuildViews to work with the SiteMapProvider? Is there a tag I am missing in web.config or something similar?